# PHP Assosiative array Insert into if data doesnt exist in table

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have an assosiative array in PHP which is inserting data into a table

```
foreach($array as $key => $value){
        $query = "INSERT INTO live_list (file_id, date) SELECT ('$key', '$value') FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM live_list WHERE file_id = '$key')";
        mysqli_query($link, $query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysqli_error($link));
    }
```

However as I have moved from an indexed array to an assosiative array, I can't figure out how to insert this data ONLY if the data in my array does not exist in my table.

```
Query failed: Operand should contain 1 column(s)
```

Now I am recieving this error

Any help will be great!

Comment: I would use mysqli_fetch_assoc( ) to read the data stored in the database and see if it matches with what I intend to insert. If it matches, then don't do the insertion.

Comment: Ok I need to look into this and see if I can pull it off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why the use of a sub-query?

Assuming `file_id` is a unique field (i.e. no duplicates in the whole table), make it a unique index on the table if it isn't already:

```
ALTER TABLE live_list
ADD UNIQUE (file_id)
```

and change your query to

```
INSERT INTO live_list (file_id, date) 
 VALUES ('$key', '$value') 
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE date = date;
```

This means that it will simple "update" the value of `date` to what it already is if it encounters a duplicate key.

Although you should look to bind your parameters to protect against sql injection.

Comment: I already had this, but I need to check if the key value exists in my table, if it does I dont want to insert it.

Comment: Thanks I had to change it to a unique field to get this working as you said

Comment: Glad it worked. Do look into [prepared statements/bind parameters](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) as I mentioned or your program could be vulnerable. Regardless it is good practise.

Comment: Thanks I will look into this however, I had sorted my values by most recent date, now I have added Unique, it scrambles my file ids in a random order, even though before I insert the records they are sorted using uasort function

Comment: It doesn't matter what order you insert your data in the table. MySQL will sort by the first column in a `SELECT` query unless you specify a `ORDER BY column_name ASC/DESC`.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
INSERT INTO live_list (file_id, date) 
  SELECT '$key', '$value'
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM live_list WHERE file_id = '$key')
```

DUAL is a dummy table. The logic is that if the sub query does not exist, the dummy table returns one row with the desiered input.

Comment: I tried this and I got a parse error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'mysqli_query' (T_STRING)

Comment: $query = "INSERT INTO live_list (file_id, date) SELECT ('$key', '$value') FROM dual WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM live_list WHERE file_id = '$key')"

Comment: Ahh no semi colon haha.

Comment: Now I have Query failed: Operand should contain 1 column(s)

Comment: Maybe you have two identical file_id? Try adding a limit to the sub query: INSERT INTO live_list (file_id, date) 
  SELECT '$key', '$value'
  FROM dual
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM live_list WHERE file_id = '$key' LIMIT 1)